# \r\n Are showing up as is, not creating new lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I input a command such as "dir" through my python program it prints out what it should except that instead of being neat and organised, its all a continuous line and spammed with either \r or \n . Does anyone know the solution for that?

Client:

```
import socket
import subprocess


def execute_sys_command(command):
    return subprocess.check_output((command).decode(), shell=True)


connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection.connect(("127.0.0.1", 4444))



while True:
    command = connection.recv(1024)
    command_result = execute_sys_command(command)
    connection.send(command_result)

connection.close()
```

Btw, I get the input from another program remotely.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the Server.

```
import socket

listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listener.bind(("127.0.0.1", 4444))
listener.listen(0)
print("[+] Waiting for incoming connections")
connection, address = listener.accept()
print("[+] Connection received from " + str(address))

while True:
    command = input(">> ").encode()
    connection.send(command)
    result = connection.recv(1024)
    command = (command).decode("utf-8")
    print(result)
```

At the end, its printing the result from the previous one.

Comment: Where is the `print` in your code?

Comment: Seems like you are displaying the `str` *object* that holds those values, but you want the `print`-ed objected

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add the other program. Thought it wasn't necesary. So the other program, which is printing the result from for example, "dir", is giving me the error previously mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out a simple solution though not the most effective way.

I replaced

```
return subprocess.check_output((command).decode(), shell=True)
```

to

```
return subprocess.getoutput((command).decode())
```

Then, I encoded it like so:

```
command_result = command_result.encode('utf-8').strip()
```

And on the recieving program, I decoded the result with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your output also starts with `b`. According to [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), the return value of `subprocess.check_output` is also a byte sequence that you will need to decode.

As an example, check out [this fiddle](https://repl.it/repls/RareTrueInstitution).

The code

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output("dir", shell=True))
```

will output

```
b'_test_runner.py  main.py\n'
```

with the sequence ending in `\n` rather than `\r\n` because repl.it is probably running on a *nix machine. If the fiddle is changed to

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output("dir", shell=True).decode())
```

then it will output

```
_test_runner.py  main.py
```

In your case, you should change the return value of `execute_sys_command`.

```
def execute_sys_command(command):
    return subprocess.check_output((command).decode(), shell=True).decode()
```

I did not notice this until reading your code a few more times, but I think that

```
command = (command).decode("utf-8")
```

was meant to decode the `result` rather than the `command`.

Note that because you are running on a Windows machine, the encoding may not be `utf-8` but rather `cp1252` or `iso-8859-1`.

I am almost certain this is the case. Looking at [the ISO-8859-1 code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout) (of which Windows-1252 is a superset), `0xa3` corresponds to the pound sterling sign.

```
print(b'\xa3'.decode('utf-8'))
```

The line above will result in your error, `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 0: invalid start byte`.

```
print(b'\xa3'.decode('cp1252'))
```

The line above will result in `£`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! When I try to decode the result, it prompts me this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 52: invalid start byte`

Comment: And also, when trying to decode the return value a syntax error appears.

Comment: If you intended to send a `£` in your byte sequence, then the issue may be related to incorrect encodings. As for the syntax error, that was my bad. I had added an extra parenthesis at the end of the return statement.